# images is not inserting into database

Tags: php, image, mysqli, insert

i have created a image uploading  page in php. the images are stored fine in root folder but not inserting into database.i dont know what i am doing wrong................

here is my code

html

```
form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="upload" name='submit'>
</form>
```

php

```
$con=........

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $file=$_FILES['file'];

   $filename= $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
   $temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   $error=$_FILES['file']['error'];

   $ext=explode('.', $filename);
   $actual=strtolower(end($ext));

   $allowed=array('jpg','png','jpeg');

   if (in_array($actual,$allowed)) {
       if ($error ===0) {
           if ($size <5000000) {
               $desti= 'uploads/'.$filename;
               move_uploaded_file($temp,$desti);
           }else{
            echo"limit is 50 mb";
           }
       }else{
        echo"network error";
       }
   }else{
       echo"wrong file type";
   }

   $res=mysqli_query($con, "insert into images('image') values('$desti')");
```

Comment: Database table:         id  image name des

Comment: Did you debug values? What path is given for saving? Did you find where process is broken? echo the SQL statement before querying it and try to run in any SQL client to check if it doesn't contain any errors.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''image') values('$desti')' at line 1

Comment: column names do NOT get encased in quotes - use backticks instead. Also - if you use a `prepared statement` you would not have had this issue

Comment: first just echo your insert statement and see what's wrong. Try to run it in SQL client and fix all problems.

Comment: why use backtik

Comment: You do not need to use backticks with the column name `image` as it is not a reserved keyword but imo it is good practise to do so

Comment: "*why use backtik*" cause specification requires that? for column names you can use backiticks or nothing, but cannot use single quotes. Ask MySQL's or Maria DB's engineers why is that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code shown above is the actual code and that your sql has single quotes surrounding the column names then change the sql from

```
$res=mysqli_query($con, "insert into images('image') values('$desti')");
```

to

```
$sql='insert into `images` (`image`) values (?)';
$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$desti);
$stmt->execute();
```